# Proving expectation is finite.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X_1, X_2, \dotsc, X_n$ be a sequence of iid.

How do I show that if for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $\mathbb{P}\big(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{X_1+X_2+\dotsb+X_n}{n}=c\big)>0$, then $E(|X_1|)<\infty$ and $E(X_1)=c$.

I’m thinking by contradiction ($E(|X|) = \infty$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $S_n$ be the partial sums. The event  $\{S_n/n \to c\}$ is a tail event for the variables $\{X_i\}$, so the hypothesis and the Kolmogorov zero-one law imply that it has probability one. Therefore,
$$\frac{S_{n-1}}{n} =\frac{S_{n-1}}{n-1} \cdot \frac{n-1}{n} \to c \quad \text{a.s.}\,,$$
so subtraction yields $\:\: X_n/n \to 0 \; \; \text{a.s.} \quad (*)$

On the other hand, $|X_1| \le  \sum_{n=0}^\infty {\bf 1}_{|X_1| \ge n}$, so
$$E(|X_1|) \le E\Bigl(\sum_{n=0}^\infty {\bf 1}_{|X_1| \ge n}\Bigr) =\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(|X_1| \ge n)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(|X_n| \ge n) \,.$$
If $E|X_1|=\infty$ then the second Borel-Cantelli Lemma would imply that
$|X_n|\ge n$ infinitely often almost surely, contradicting $(*)$.
Thus $E|X_1|<\infty$, and the strong law of large numbers implies $EX_1=c$.

Comment: I think the OP stated convergence only in a set of positive measure. The a.s. convergence is follows from a 0-1 law right?

Comment: Yes, will add this. Thanks

Comment: How do we get the first inequality? $E(|X_1|)\leq\sum^\infty_{n=0}P(|X_1|\geq n)$

Comment: @Taffy, I added an explanation of this to my answer.